# Json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token: как решить?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp

При отправке GET запроса на сервер получаю:

> data.json?callback=jQuery1111073…*1539940574412&*=1539940574413:2
>     Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json',
  jsonCallback: 'data',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(json) {
    alert(json);
  }
});
```

Comment: покажите ответ, который возвращает сервер. Скорее всего там ошибка синтаксическая

Comment: {
  "data": [
    "affenpinscher",
    "whippet"  ]
}   Указывает на двоеточие после data

Comment: Это весь полученный ответ?

Comment: http://webmogilev.by/index2.html вот сами гляньте

Comment: это валидный `json`, а что за функция в `callback`? _jQuery1111073..._

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы выполнить запрос ajax в jsonp, необходимо чтобы сервер отдавал ответ в специальной обертке, по этой ссылке http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json отдается обычный json. Вот тут можно почитать https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-jsonp .

Кроссдоменный ajax в json вы не сможете сделать, из-за ограничений браузера.
Как вариант, можно сделать ajax запрос к себе на бекенд (не jsonp), а оттуда уже выполнить кроссдоменных запрос, например, curl-ом, и вернуть результаты себе в javascript.

Вот пример использваний curl на PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: почему не смогу кросдоменно, jsonp позволяет же это делать

Comment: Потому что тут http://www.mrsoft.by/data.json отдается обычный json.А jsonp ответ - это json, обернутый в callback функцию